# Winrt StreamWriter & StorageFile does not completely Overwrite File

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, streamwriter

Quick search here yielded nothing.  So, I have started using some rather roundabout ways to use StreamWriter in my WinRT Application.  Reading works well, writing works differently.  What' I'm seeing is that when I select my file to write, if I choose a new file then no problem.  The file is created as I expect.  If I choose to overwrite a file, then the file is overwritten to a point, but the point where the stream stops writing, if the original file was large, then the old contents exist past where my new stream writes.

The code is as such:

```
public async void WriteFile(StorageFile selectedFileToSave)
{
    // At this point, selectedFileToSave is from the Save File picker so can be a enw or existing file
    StreamWriter writeStream;
    Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
    Stream dotNetStream;

    dotNetStream = await selectedFileToSave.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    StreamWriter writeStream = new StreamWriter(dotNetStream, enc);

    // Do writing here

    // Close
    writeStream.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    await writeStream.FlushAsync();
    await dotNetStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Can anyone offer clues on what I could be missing?   There are lots of functions missing in WinRT, so not really following ways to get around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the helper methods in [`FileIO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx) class? You could call:

```
FileIO.WriteTextAsync(selectedFileToSave, newTextContents);
```

If you really need a `StreamWriter`, first truncate the file by calling

```
FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(selectedFileToSave, new byte[0]);
```

And then continue with your existing code.

Comment: FileIO didn't work well, seems that it wants you to put together all your data first and then output it rather than doing it incrementally.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can set length of the stream to 0 with `SetLength` method before using `StreamWriter`:

```
var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
stream.SetLength(0);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(text);
}
```