# xml XDocument Save modify file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I am trying to add `XElements` to an `XDocument`. I am trying to move from using inifile to xml but I am having some issues here.

This is my `C#` code:

```
public static async Task<List<XElement>> XMLHandling()
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sFile.xml");

            List<XElement> doc;
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(fileStream).Descendants("signals").ToList();
                //avoid range check
                doc[0].Add(new XElement("Character", new XElement("Value", "value1"), new XElement("Description", "This is some text")));
                using (Stream sr = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    doc[0].Save(sr);
                }
            }
            //example
            return doc;
        }
```

This is how the file look before:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <signals>

   </signals>

   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

and this is how it becomes after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<signals>
  <Character>
    <Value>value1</Value>
    <Description>This is some text</Description>
  </Character>
</signals>/title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I can't even understand why and I can't debug this.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please post what you expect as the output.  Not what you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two things wrong here.

First, you're not saving what you thing you are.

```
doc = XDocument.Load(fileStream).Descendants("signals").ToList();
```

Here, `doc` is list of `signals` elements.

```
doc[0].Add(new XElement("Character", new XElement("Value", "value1"), 
    new XElement("Description", "This is some text")));
```

Here, you add a `Character` element to the first `signals` element.

```
doc[0].Save(sr);
```

And finally, you save **only** the first `signals` element. That explains why you see a `signals` at the start of your 'new' document.

Secondly, you're not truncating the file you're writing to. This is why you see some garbled XML after the end of your `signals` element - this is simply what was in the file originally, you've just overwritten the first part of it. You might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425396/winrt-streamwriter-storagefile-does-not-completely-overwrite-file) for some options to handle this. One option is just to set the length to zero before you write to it.

So, something like this:

```
XDocument doc;

using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
}

var signals = doc.Descendants("signals").Single();

signals.Add(new XElement("Character", ...));

using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    stream.SetLength(0);
    doc.Save(stream);
}
```